# WPF converters: where does the culture come from

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, converters

I've created a WPF converter class:

```
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //blah blah
    }
}
```

I wonder who sets the culture parameter that is passed. I would expect it to be the same as the current windows settings, but it appears to be different.

Anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This page](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/04/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times.html) describes a bug (feature?) of WPF where culture will always be en-US unless you take action to specify otherwise and how to fix it.

Comment: Oh... my god. Alright, well... That explains things.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, using the technique described on [that page](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/04/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times.html) is a bad idea -- it doesn't take into account any customisations that the user has made to their formatting settings in the Control Panel.

Instead, just ignore the culture parameter passed in to the converter entirely; if you need to pass a culture on to something else, use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.  (Since this is the default for Parse and ToString, you usually don't need to pass it on anyway.)