# Enable/Disable Combobox if label content changed

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to enable/disable the combobox if the label has content in the xaml? (I am looking for a **xaml** solution.)

```
<Label x:Name="lbl_AusgewählteEmail" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="37,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607"
    Content="{Binding ElementName=combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="combx_Auswahl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="37,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure XAML, no. You can however use an `IValueConverter` to turn that string into a boolean:

```cs
public class NonEmptyStringToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string) value);
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <yourNameSpace:NonEmptyStringToBooleanConverter x:Key="StringToBool"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Label x:Name="lbl_AusgewählteEmail" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Margin="37,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607"
   Content="{Binding ElementName=combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="combx_Auswahl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="37,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource StringToBool}"/>
```

---

You **could** potentially also do this via a `Style` but that would be a bit weird to be honest. For the sake of completeness:

Include the following namespace at the top of your containing control/window:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```xaml
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

Comment: How about a `DataTrigger` using [string.Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582441/4610605) ? - Would that work too ?

Comment: @FelixD. Exactly what I'm trying right now :) But since we don't know if the Selected Item is `null` or has an Empty default entry it would be a wild guess. I'll include it anyways just to be sure.

Comment: We can check for `{x:Null}` **and** `string.Empty`

Comment: @FelixD. Good point ^^ Could however also be a manually created `ComboBoxItem`

Comment: CultureInfo culture - what does it mean

Comment: Its the localizaition. Some DataTypes like DateTime have a default format depending on the selected culture.

Comment: @Raizzen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801789/wpf-converters-where-does-the-culture-come-from

Comment: Iam sry but if i would use the style <ComboBox.Style> is underllined and says sth like "doesnt found". may i have to place it somewhere special  ?

Comment: @Raizzen You have to place it inside your ComboBox (`<ComboBox><ComboBox.Style>...</ComboBox.Style></ComboBox>`). What does it say exactly?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer it says sth like "attributename not found"

Comment: @Raizzen Did you include the `system` namespace? (above style example)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yeah, but its solved. I had a "/" to much.. thx for all